# Map restart when screen rotation (Android Studio)

Tags: google-maps-markers

I have a problem about screen rotation. I know that I must use method "onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)" but I have no ideal how it works. My application have to add the "marker" to Google Map.

```
class AddMarker extends Fragment{

private static final String KEY = "marker";
private ArrayList<LatLng> mData; 
private GoogleMap mMap;
private MapView mMapView; 
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putParcelableArrayList(KEY, mData);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);

    mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMap = mMapView.getMap();
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    if((savedInstanceState != null)
            && (savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(KEY) != null)){
        mData = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(KEY);
      // What should I do here ????
      // call drawMarker(mData) ???
    }
    else
        drawMarker(mData);
    return v;
}
```

}
}